# PHP Application Deployment with Capistrano

Tags: php, deployment, capistrano

Why does Capistrano try to create a new branch when I run a deployment of my PHP application?  My SCM is Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the branch is only used internally to ensure a clean working directory, from which to copy the release files.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, people tend to create a branch when they release an application to their production environment.

This way :

- They can continue activelly working on the main *(development)* branch,
- And, if needed, they can fix critical bugs on the release branch *-- that one not being impacted by the current developments*.

And they don't create a branch as soon as they deploy, they often at least create a tag -- from which they can branch if there is a bug that needs to be fixed before the next release of the development branch.

Comment: What if you deploy your application from the release branch always?  This follows Eric Sink's recommendation for deploying web applications: http://www.ericsink.com/vcbe/html/web_development.html.  Would it be possible to suppress the checkout?

Comment: In this case, there's probably a way to indicate to capistrano that it must not create a branch *(I've worked with capistrano a couple of times, and it has never created a branch automatically -- too bad I've never looked how it was configured)*